# Insert date in MSaccess database.

Tags: sql, date, dojo

I want to perform an insert query to insert some set of values which include dates also. I am getting Data type mismatch error.

In My access database i have set Ass_date`(as Short date(Format 4/13/2012)(i.e MM/dd/yyyy))` and Ass_Time`(as Long Time(Format 5:13:00PM(i.e hh:mm:ss tt))` and same goes for Sch_Date and Sch_Time.

I am making user enter a value from DojoDateTextBox for date and DojoTimeTextBox for Time And when user enters a value i get them in the form of String In this format Date `(2012-04-13)` and Time`(T17:45:00)( which is 5:45:00PM)`. I retrieve these values using ::

```
String assdate = request.getParameter("assigneddatename");
String asstime = request.getParameter("assignedtimename");
```

And them i am inserting it into database using Query ::

```
String sql2= "insert into ATT_Table(Assigned_To_ID,Assigned_By_ID,Env_ID,Product_ID,Project_ID,Act_Number,Act_Type,Status,Sch_Date,Sch_Time,Ass_Date,Ass_Time,Percent_Complete,Description,Comments) values('"+var1+"','"+var2+"',"+var3+","+var4+","+var5+","+actnum+",'"+acttype+"','"+status+"',#"+schdate+"#,"+schtime+",#"+assdate+"#,"+asstime+","+percent+",'"+descr+"','"+comm+"')";
```

Please help me out as to how to insert the value of a date in database. Thanks .

Answer (score 0):

Time is also a date datatype. You'll need to wrap the times in '#' symbols as you have done for the dates.